# separate string with characters as number and ) in C#

Tags: c#

I don't have much experience in C#. i am getting string from DB like

`string strType = "1) Step to start workorder 1 2)step 2 continue 3)issue of workorder4)create workorder by name"  // String is not fixed any numbers of Steps can be included.`

I wanted to separate out above string like

```
1)step to start workorder
2)step 2 continue
3)issue of workorder  
4)create workorder by name    (SO ON.....)
```

i tried following but its static if i get more step it will fail....also solution is not good

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "1)", "2)", "3)", "4)" };  
string[] strNames = strType.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None );  
foreach (string strName in firstNames)  
        Console.WriteLine(strName);
```

How can I separate out string based on **number** and **)** characters. best solution for any string...

Comment: There is absolutely no chance, that "n)" can be part of the text? It will _always_ be a separator?

Comment: nop.....they are like steps clients sends to represent but get it as string which needs to be presented the way i said...

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code -

```
  var pat = @"\d+[\)]";
    var str=  "1) Step to start workorder 1 2)step 2 continue 3)issue of workorder40)create workorder by name";
    var rgx = new Regex(pat);
    var output = new List<string>();

    var matches = rgx.Matches(str);

    for(int i=0;i<matches.Count-1;i++)
    {
        output.Add(str.Substring(matches[i].Index, matches[i+1].Index- matches[i].Index));
        Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(matches[i].Index, matches[i + 1].Index - matches[i].Index));
    }

    output.Add(str.Substring(matches[matches.Count - 1].Index));
    Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(matches[matches.Count - 1].Index));
```

Comment: A little more sophisticated regex will do all that for you. See https://regex101.com/r/t39Y1M/1/

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward approach is to split this string using a regular expression, and then work with the matched substrings:

```cs
string strType = "1) Step to start workorder 1 2)step 2 continue 3)issue of workorder4)create workorder by name";

var matches = Regex.Matches(strType, @"\d+\).*?(?=\d\)|$)");
foreach(Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

This will print

```
1) Step to start workorder 1
2)step 2 continue
3)issue of workorder
4)create workorder by name
```

The regular expression works as follows:

- `\d+\)`: Match `"n)"`, where `n` is any decimal number
- `.*?`: Match all characters until...
- `(?=\d\)|$)`: either the next `"n)"` follows, or the input string end is reached (this is called a lookahead)

---

If you want to cleanly replace the numbering by one with a more consistent formatting, you might use

```cs
string strType = "1) Step to start workorder 1 2)step 2 continue 3)issue of workorder4)create workorder by name";

int ctr = 0;
var matches = Regex.Matches(strType, @"\d+\)\s*(.*?)(?=\d\)|$)");
foreach(Match match in matches)
    if(match.Groups.Count > 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"{++ctr}) {match.Groups[1]}");
```

...which outputs

```
1) Step to start workorder 1
2) step 2 continue
3) issue of workorder
4) create workorder by name
```

The regular expression works similarly to first approach:

- `\d+\)\s*`: Match `"n)"` and any following whitespace (to address inconsistent spacing)
- `(.*?)`: Match all characters and use this as match group #1
- `(?=\d\)|$)`: Lookahead, same as above

Note that only the match group #1 is printed, so the "n)" and the whitespace are omitted.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i tried solution but only last step added.with 1)..like only 1) create workorder by name gets output........

Comment: Did you copy&paste this code to your program? I've tested it, it is working perfectly on my system. Also, which runtime environment (e.g. .NET version) are you using?

Comment: sorry i guess i made mistake in foreach output stream....i was getting last output as 1) test   i have given my string.....i will rectify my mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the schema is:

```
"[{number})Text] [{number})Text] [{number})Text]..."
```

Here is a solution:

```
  string strType = "1) Step to start workorder 1 2)step 2 continue 3)issue of workorder 4)create workorder by name";

  var result = new List<string>();

  int count = strType.Count(c => c == ')');
  if ( count > 0 )
  {
    int posCurrent = strType.IndexOf(')');
    int delta = posCurrent - 1;
    if ( count == 1 && posCurrent > 0)
      result.Add(strType.Trim());
    else
    {
      posCurrent = strType.IndexOf(')', posCurrent + 1);
      int posFirst = 0;
      int posSplit = 0;
      do
      {
        for ( posSplit = posCurrent - 1; posSplit >= 0; posSplit--)
          if ( strType[posSplit] == ' ' )
            break;
        if ( posSplit != -1 && posSplit > posFirst)
        {
          result.Add(strType.Substring(posFirst, posSplit - posFirst - 1 - 1 + delta).Trim());
          posFirst = posSplit + 1;
        }
        posCurrent = strType.IndexOf(')', posCurrent + 1);
      }
      while ( posCurrent != -1 && posFirst != -1 );
      result.Add(strType.Substring(posFirst).Trim());
    }
  }

  foreach (string item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I am really one of those "solve a problem with regex - now you you have 2 problems"-guys , but here, regex will boil this down to ~ 4 readable lines of code ...

Comment: The OP can choose with or without regex depending of his knowledge and his faith and what he wants to learn.

Answer (score -1):

You may use Regular Expression to achieve it. Following is code for your reference:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string expr = @"\d+\)";
string[] matches = Regex.Split(strType, expr);
foreach(string m in matches){
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

My system does not have Visual Studio, so please test it in yours. It should be working with minor tweaks.

Comment: That will cut out the "n)". I'd try matching something like this: https://regex101.com/r/t39Y1M/1/ instead of split.

Comment: As I said, I do not have access to VS now. You just need to find the correct regular expression and it will work. Also, you may add numbering to the values. I think this should be continuous numbers only.

Comment: yes continues numbers...its likes steps to reproduce some issue..but steps may vary....some time more then 10 or less then 10 like.....